# Two ways of defining a string variable in swift

Tags: string, swift, variables

I was just wondering if these two forms of defining a variable differ from each other. Or should one be used in some special scenario.

```
var string1: String  {
    return "ok"
}

var string2: String = "ok"
```

Comment: It's not a variable, it's a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First approach is so called [computed property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259):

> Classes, structures, and enumerations can define computed properties, which do not actually store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

The form you use provides only a getter for `string1` which makes it a read-only property.

---

The second approach declares usual [stored property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID255):

> A stored property is a constant or variable that is stored as part of an instance of a particular class or structure. Stored properties can be either variable stored properties (introduced by the var keyword) or constant stored properties (introduced by the let keyword).

In your case it is a read-write property (declared using `var` keyword).

---

Which should be used when depends on the case.  But sometimes it's only possible to introduce computed properties only (e.g. in case if you are providing an extension).

Answer (score 2):

In first case you create `get` for your `string1` object and you will not be able to set new value for it. This case is the same of:

```
var string1: String {
    get {
        return "ok1"
    }
}
```

In second case you create `string2` object with value `ok` and you can get it from object and set the new value for it